# Filter is not working in ios

Tags: ios, filtering, nspredicate

i used the NsPredicate to Filter the NSMutableArray By one & multiple Values,First i tried by to filter By Price,
i have saved the NSDictionary Value to the NSMutableArray  (i.e) resultArray,here is my code help me,

```
    for (int i=0; i<=resultArray.count; i++)
    {
            NSDictionary *dict=resultArray[i];
            NSLog(@"Dict %@",dict);
            NSPredicate *predit=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Price == %@)", @"100"];
            NSArray *resultAr = [[dict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predit];
            NSLog(@"Output %@",resultAr);
    }


Dict {
    Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
    Percentage = 0;
    Price = 80;
}
```

And Result Array is:

```
 Result (
        {
        Name = "Black Eyed Peas";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 80;
    },
        {
        Name = "Black Gram";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 56;
    },
        {
        Name = "Channa White";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Double Beans";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 95;
    },
        {
        Name = "Gram Dall";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Green Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    },
        {
        Name = "Ground Nut";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 140;
    },
        {
        Name = "Moong Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 75;
    },
        {
        Name = "Orid Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 100;
    },
        {
        Name = "Toor Dal";
        Percentage = 0;
        Price = 150;
    }
)
```

Expected Output is

```
(
            {
            Name = "Channa White";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        },
            {
            Name = "Gram Dall";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        },          
            {
            Name = "Orid Dal";
            Percentage = 0;
            Price = 100;
        }
)
```

but it giving the Error

```
 reason: '[<__NSCFNumber 0x146db5e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Price.
```

above code is correct for filtering else give me a idea to filter the resultArray for expected output

Comment: Add interface of the array content type.

Comment: Seems like `[dict allValues]` returns array, that contains `NSNumber` object. Carefully check, what your `dict` actually contains

Comment: Can you `NSLog(@"%@", [dict allValues])` and updated your question with the result.

Comment: now i update my full Question

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below code.I use predicate here.

```
        NSPredicate *predit=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Price like %@",100];
        NSArray *resultAr = [resultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predit];
```

In above code

If you give **LIKE** it gives same price data.

You have to Delete or remove [dict allValues] from the code.

Instead of [dict allValues] you need to add resultArray.Because it is array.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't create a regex expression from object 100.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: i already told it's not working & getting the error  
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't create a regex expression from object 100.' *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

You Have Array like this

```
NSArray *arr = @[@{
                     @"Name": @"Black Eyed Peas",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"80"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Black Gram",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"56"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Channa White",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"100"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Double Beans",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"95"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Gram Dall",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"100"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Green Moong Dal",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"150"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Ground Nut",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"140"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Moong Dal",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"75"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Orid Dal",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"100"
                     },
                 @{
                     @"Name" : @"Toor Dal",
                     @"Percentage" : @"0",
                     @"Price" : @"150"
                     }];
```

You just have to use predicate on this array like

```
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Price like %@",@"100"];
NSArray *arr2 = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and you're getting all values from array which have price 100

Comment: i've tested it myself,and it's working fine. so that i've put that code here